# Django contraint filtered models to include set that matches first criteria

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to iterate over user matching entities to avoid grouping in helper array first.

How from query like this I can make User.stone_set to contain only ones that matched the filter?

```
users = User.objects.filter(payment__due_day__lte=datetime.today()+3)
```

Now each user should have only payment instances that mateched the filter, but users.payment_set is a manager not really related to it.

**Clarification**

Here is my model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
   due_day = models.IntegerField()
```

now, query like this: `User.objects.filter(payment__due_day=10)` will give me users that have payment due day 10. Now iterating over those users objects I want it to have only those payment I queried for the first time (only those that have payment with due_day = 10), without quering single user again for their payments.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? it is hard to understand what you are looking to achieve. May be an example would help !

Comment: Paste models, put an example, help us to help you.

Comment: posted a clarification, hope this will explain it in more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, in the end you want a queryset of `Payment` objects. 
Then, start from that model, not `User`.

```
payments = Payment.objects.filter(due_day=10).select_related('owner').order_by('owner')
```

After that, you can iterate over the queryset and get the owner (user) of each payment without any extra query, because `select_related` will do a SQL join for you in the background.

The `order_by` clause is needed if you have multiple payments for each user and you need to show that. In your template you can use the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) built-in template tag.

For example:

```
# In your view (EXTREMELY simplified)
def my_view(request):
    payments = Payment.objects.filter(due_day=10).select_related('owner').order_by('owner')
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'payments': payments})

# In your template
{% regroup payments by owner as payment_list %}
<ul>
    {% for payment in payment_list %}
    <li>{{ payment.grouper }} <!-- this is the owner -->
        <ul>
        {% for item in payment.list %}
          <li>{{ item.due_day }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If, instead, you want to achieve that in bare python, the best solution is to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (which is, in fact, used by the `regroup` tag).

A quick and untested example:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

payments = Payment.objects.filter(due_day=10).select_related('owner').order_by('owner')

for owner, grouped_payments in groupby(payments, attrgetter('owner')):
    do_stuff_with(owner)
    do_some_other_stuff_with(list(grouped_payments))
```

Be sure to read the docs.

Comment: regroup sounds great! Didn't know about it. How to achive that in bare python not in template? I want that to be used in command. Moreover I wanted to iterate over Owner to be able to send emails about the upcoming payments in single iteration for each user.